# Guardar datos de checkboxes en BBDD desde PHP

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

Tengo las siguientes tablas en mi base de datos:

```
CREATE TABLE subjects (
  subject_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  subject text,
  PRIMARY KEY (subject_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE users (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  username varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE users_subjects (
  users_subjects_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id_fk int(11),
  subject_id_fk int(11),
  FOREIGN KEY(user_id_fk) REFERENCES users(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(subject_id_fk) REFERENCES subjects(subject_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (users_subjects_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

En la tabla 'users_subjects' estoy relacionando las tablas ‘subjects’ y ‘users’.

Además, todos los datos en las tablas se van ingresando desde mi index.php. Por lo tanto, cada vez que introduzco un nuevo ‘subject’ desde mi index.php, se crean ‘checkboxes’ como éstas en la parte donde se agrega el usuario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código  para ingresar al usuario, donde los ‘checkboxes’ se forman cada vez que se introduce una asignatura: -------- index.php:

```
<form method="post" action="register.php">
    <?php include('errors.php'); ?>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>User</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label>Subjects</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT subject FROM subjects"; /*Select from table name: subjects*/
        $result = $conn->query($sql); /*Check connection*/
        if($result)
        {
            foreach($result as $row)
            {
                echo "<input type='checkbox' name='subject[]' value='" . htmlspecialchars($row['subject']) . "' /> <label>" . $row['subject'] . " </label><br>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn" name="reg_user">Add new user</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Hasta ahora, cada vez que se ingresa el nombre de usuario, se almacena en la taba ‘users’ correctamente.

El problema que tengo es que no sé cómo guardar los ‘checkboxes’ en la tabla ‘users_subjects’. No consigo resolverlo. ¿Puede alguien ayudarme?

Este es el código que he hecho para ‘register.php’:

```
<?php
$username = "";
$subject = "";
$errors = array();

include('Conexion.php');

if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) { 
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];


    if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
    if (empty($subject)) { array_push($errors, "Subject is required"); }

    $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $user_check_query);
    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    if ($user) { // if user exists
        if ($user['username'] === $username) {
            array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
        }
    }

    if (count($errors) == 0) {

        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username)    VALUES('$username')";
        mysqli_query($conn, $query);


/*Aquí es donde estoy atascada*/
        $insert_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
        //$str = serialize($subject); /*To make the array into a string*/
        //$arrSubject = unserialize($str); /*To turn the serialized string back into an array:*/
        $subject=implode(',',$_POST['subject']);
        //Count subjects and checks if the subject exists
        for($i=0; $i<count($subject); $i++) {

            $query = "SELECT subject_id FROM subject where subject='$subject[$i]'";
            $result = $conn->query($query); /*Check connection*/

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                $subject_id = $row["subject_id"];
                $query = "INSERT INTO users_subjects (user_id_fk, subject_id_fk)
           VALUES('$insert_id', '$subject_id')";
                mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            }
        }
        header('location: index.php');
    }
}
?>
```

He añadido el comentario `/*Aquí es donde estoy atascada*/` en ‘register.php’ para indicar donde tengo problemas.

Comment: Hola @ana cuando tu ejecutas el tu script te genera algún error en pantalla. Si es así por favor de colocarlo

Comment: Hola @YoelRodriguez, no se genera ningún error en la pantalla, pero tampoco guarda nada en la tabla 'users_subjects '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LO que te esta sucediendo, es que el **array** que estas tomando del formulario lo estas pasando a un **string** por lo que el ciclo **for** no te ejecuta el código en su interior. Esto es debido a que el método **count()** devuelve 0 porque el valor que le estas pasado es un **string** y no un **array**   .

Desde el formulario, ya estas definiendo que  `$_POST['subject']` y es un **array** y lo haces de la siguiente manera `name='subject[]'` por lo que solo tienes que asignar el valor del `$_POST['subject']` a la variable `$subject`.

El método **implode()** lo quitas de esa linea que lo que haces es pasarte el **array** a **string**. A continuación te dejo la modificación del código.

**Antes:**

```
$subject=implode(',',$_POST['subject']);
```

**Cambiar:**

```
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
```

Comment: Gracias!! Me ha ayudado mucho tu respuesta :D

Comment: De nada, me alegra que te fuera útil muchas gracias